# How to CSS onclick redirect?

Tags: css, redirect

I'm trying to redirect website visitors to other websites through css onclick redirects.

1. Is it possible open new window ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing questions that best enable the community to provide helpful direction.  What is a "css onclick redirect"?  Are you asking if you can use CSS to change the target of a clicked anchor?  Would it be possible to include a [mcve] that illustrates what you are attempting?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "css onclick".    There are onclick events in JavaScript, is that what you meant?    CSS (cascading style sheets) are used to change how a page looks.   They are not used to specify behavior when a user clicks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"_blank"` this opens the linked document in a new window.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <style>
                html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
             }

                .full-height {
                height: 100%;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body >
            <div class="full-height" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank')">
            <p>page content</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: bro... it's only button...i need full window.

Comment: Do you mean if you click anywhere on the page redirect to another page

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: have you any solution??

Comment: Rather than create a second answer, you can [edit] this one.  Please delete your other answer and put you updates into your existing answer.